# ECMAScript version mismatch between Typescript compiler and IntelliSense

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I am trying to build a node.js application using Typescript in Visual Studio 2015, and since I want to use Promises, I chose in the Project settings ECMAScript 6.

Now, when I try to build the project, it works fine, but IntelliSense keeps telling me that I may not use await, because for that I would have to target ECMAScript 6 or higher.

Is there a seperate setting in Visual Studio to set the IntelliSense target version that I overlooked?

**EDIT**: Added screenshot of project settings

[image: Typescript project settings]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a seperate setting in Visual Studio to set the IntelliSense target version that I overlooked

Perhaps your project also contains a `tsconfig.json` file. Make sure it has its `compilerOptions.target` set to `es6`.

Comment: There is no `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Maybe you have resharper that is complaining and not visual studio

Comment: No resharper either, no addons except ones from Microsoft.

Comment: Can you add a project settings screenshot to your question. Please leave a message here once done

Comment: I attached the screenshot. Thanks so far for helping me!

Comment: Personally don't use Visual studio at all for TypeScript. Your screenshot looks right ... might be a VS bug

Comment: Report here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+await